# Is valid casting an `enum` to other `enum` in [C]?

Tags: c, enums, casting, standards

I have two enums.

```
enum A { A1=1, A2=2 }

enum B { B1=1, B2=2 }
```

Is this valid by standard of C?

```
A a = A1;
B b = a;
```

(compiled well with Clang, but I can't sure this is standard or extension behavior)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's valid by the standard, but the C99 spec mentions that some implementations may generate a warning:

> An implementation may generate warnings in many situations, none of which are specified as part of this International Standard. The following are a few of the more common situations.
>
> - A value is given to an object of an enumerated type other than by assignment of an enumeration constant that is a member of that type, or an enumeration variable that has the same type, or the value of a function that returns the same enumerated type (6.7.2.2).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in C enums are basically `int`s with personality.  (This contrasts with C++ where they are full fledged types.)  So, assigning different `enum`s is effectively still just working with `int`s, so it is legal.  However, I'm not saying this is recommended :)

Answer (score 0):

It is valid Standard C but it's a bad idea. Note that it is *not* valid C++.